# change checkbox through javascript and pass the value to php

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

i have created some custom woocommerce fields and i'm changing the value of a checkbox using javascript based on some criteria.

```js
var setborder = document.getElementById("setborder");
setborder.disabled = true;
setborder.checked = true;
```

in the frontend it works perfect, however i'm passing the value of this checkbox in the cart using:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function cart_item_name( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
 if ($cart_item['setborder'] == 'on') {
        $setborder = __('with border','conditional-single-product');
    }
 return $setborder;
}
```

When the value is set to checked through Javascript, the if condition is NOT met.
of course if a user clicks the button the if condition is met.
it doesn't make sense to mee.
do you have any clues?

Comment: Question, how are you passing the value to php? is it through ajax call? 
What do you get when you print $cart_item['setborder']?

Comment: @Nesar i don't use Ajax on this scenario because users also upload files on the same form i thought that it was too much work to implement an ajax solution for this. The value is passed to php using the woocommerce hook cart_item_name.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear enough and your code snippets are somewhat confusing. However, you should make changes to the checkbox attributes (in this case the value attribute of the checkbox) using keypress or click event of the your search criteria element then update your display to visualize behavior. Then pass your value to PHP via ajax call

Answer (score 0):

For some really wierd reason the issue is resolved if i remove

```
setborder.disabled = true;
```

i found a workaround by adding

```
setborder.style.display = "none";
```

Some insight on this would be really helpful.